# Undefined variable: products in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

this is in ProductControllor

```
public function index()
    {
        $products = Product::all();
        return view('product.index', compact('products'));
    }
```

at first i want to creat index view but it show page not found so i use this
this is web.php

```
Route::get('/index', function () {
    return view('/product/index');
```

there is no error

so now i want to do seller can see All product

```
@extends('admin.includes.main_admin')
@section('title','Product Index')
@section('content')

<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        @include('admin.includes.sidebar_admin')
         <div class="col-md-9">
              <div class="panel panel-primary">
      <div class="panel-heading">All products</div>
      <div class="panel-body">
        <table class="table table-hover">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>Image</th>
              <th>Title</th>
              <th>Discription</th>
              <th>Price</th>
              <th></th>
              <th></th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            @foreach($products as $product)
            <tr>
              <td width="200"><img src="{{asset('images/'.$product->image)}}" style="width: 100%"></td>
              <td>{{$product->title}}</td>
              <td>{{$product->description}}</td>
              <td>{{$product->price}}</td>
              <td>
                <a href="" class="btn btn-success btn sm">Edit</a>
              </td>
              <td>
                <a href="" class="btn btn-danger btn sm">Delete</a>
              </td>
            </tr>
            @endforeach
          </tbody>
        </table>

        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

@endsection
```

it shows

> Undefined variable: products

how i can fix it? Please help

Comment: `return view('/product/index')` should be `return view('product.index')` and in your closure route there is no `$products` defined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this route `web.php` file

```php
Route::get('/index', function () {
    return view('/product/index');
```

to

```php
Route::get('/index', 'ProductControllor@index');
```

you could've used another way which is to pass data from the route to view without accessing the controller

```php
Route::get('/index', function () {
    $products = Product::all();
    return view('product.index', compact('products'));
}
```

for more information check out the [documention](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/routing#basic-routing)